# Some tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I found several pairs of tags that have the same meaning with very close descriptions (when there was one):

- [spectacles](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spectacles) and [glasses](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glasses)
- [shave](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shave) and [shaving](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shaving)
- [clothes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) and [clothing](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing)

I don't know which if these should be kept, and which (no pun intended) burned...

Or should they have references to the other tag added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping these synonyms prevents the duplicate tag from being created again. If we burned [clothes] now, a user could recreate the tag and then we'll have to go through making a synonym and/or merging the tags all over again.

- Help center page: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms
- List of all tag synonyms: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: I did not know there was a synonym list. How are we supposed to navigate without some type of reference to it?

Comment: @AdamZuckerman If you hit, say, tag B which is a synonym of tag A, then you'll be forwarded to tag A.